# Adding sliding subview in a frame using TabBar button of a View controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, frame

I have a Tab-Bar button on a View Controller.I want when a user press that button a sub-view sides from the corner and shows the list of buttons for specified actions and on pressing tab bar button again sub-view should slide back and disappear.This sub-view should be shown on small frame of main View. How i can accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom action to that button.
when a user presses the button check to see if the buttons view's origin is within the bounds of your main view. if it's not, slide it in, else slide it out.

I would probably do something like that:

// Call this one on viewDidLoad

-(void)createMenuButton {

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleMenu) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];   
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item;
```

}

// Make sure the menuView property was added as subview of self.view

-(void)toggleMenu {

```
if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.view.bounds, self.menuView.frame.origin)) {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.35
                     animations:^{
                         CGRect rect = self.menuView.frame;
                         rect.origin.x -= self.menuView.frame.size.width;
                         self.menuView.frame = rect;
                     }];
} else {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.35
                     animations:^{
                         CGRect rect = self.menuView.frame;
                         rect.origin.x += self.menuView.frame.size.width;
                         self.menuView.frame = rect;
                     }];
}
```

}

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I know this stuff ..But how i can do it programmatically ..Can you tell me code for this task?? ..

Comment: Please declare variable used in -(void)toggleMenu

Comment: menuView is a UIView property that holds the buttons you mentioned as subviews and is the only property used in the function.